# Adding an unmanaged extension in NEO4j

Tags: plugins, neo4j, server

I want to create a server plugin in NEO4j and for that I have created a plugin with package name as `dummy.test.neo4j.NodeExploration.exploring`. I have registered this plugin in `META-INF.services`, but when I add the reference of this package in NEO4j.conf file as

```
dbms.unmanaged_extension_classes=dummy.test.neo4j.NodeExploration=/dummy/exploring
```

I get following error.

```
Okt 16 16:59:58 gaurav-GB-BSi3-6100 neo4j[23592]: Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer-70a4d58d@3429429d==org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer,-1,false
Okt 16 16:59:58 gaurav-GB-BSi3-6100 neo4j[23592]: org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:633)
Okt 16 16:59:58 gaurav-GB-BSi3-6100 neo4j[23592]:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:395)
Okt 16 16:59:58 gaurav-GB-BSi3-6100 neo4j[23592]:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:871)
Okt 16 16:59:58 gaurav-GB-BSi3-6100 neo4j[23592]:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:298)
Okt 16 16:59:58 gaurav-GB-BSi3-6100 neo4j[23592]:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
Okt 16 16:59:58 gaurav-GB-BSi3-6100 neo4j[23592]:  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
Okt 16 16:59:58 gaurav-GB-BSi3-6100 neo4j[23592]: at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
Okt 16 16:59:58 gaurav-GB-BSi3-6100 neo4j[23592]: at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
Okt 16 16:59:58 gaurav-GB-BSi3-6100 neo4j[23592]: at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
```

I think I'm not sure whether I'm adding correct reference in NEO4j.conf file

Comment: Can you share some code ? Have you done a plugin or an unmanagedextension ?

Answer (score 0):

The above exception is caused when we consider both server plugin and unmanaged extension concept at same time. For I just removed  line

```
dbms.unmanaged_extension_classes=dummy.test.neo4j.NodeExploration=/dummy/exploring
```

from neo4j.conf and simply called post a get request on  http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/exploring/graphdb/exploring

where exploring is my class and function name